# Why is array empty after appending object to it

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, append

I am working in a TableViewController that I am trying to fill up with data from a plist.

I declared this at the top:

```
var studentsArray:Array<StudentData>?
```

And now I am doing the following in a function that loads my plist:

```
    var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("students", withExtension: "plist")
    let tmpArray = NSArray(contentsOfURL: path!)

    for studentDict in tmpArray!{
        let name = studentDict["name"]as! String
        let dateOfBirth = studentDict["dateOfBirth"] as! NSDate
        let regular = studentDict["regular"] as! Bool
        let photoFileName = studentDict["photoFileName"] as! String

        let data = StudentData(name : name, dateOfBirth: dateOfBirth, regular : regular, photoFileName: photoFileName)

        self.studentsArray?.append(data)
        println(studentsArray!.count)

    }
```

I tried logging the properties of the Object, they are all being filled in, but it goes wrong at the `.append` and somehow it just won't do that. The array's count remains 'Nil' when logged.

I'm kind of lost here! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: var studentsArray:[StudentData] = []

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Thank you so much, worked like a charm!

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus, you should post your comment as an answer. You were the first one to provide a correct solution.

Comment: @DuncanC Will M. answered the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't look like you are initializing studentsArray anywhere. Make sure to do that. For the record, array.count should be 0 if the array is empty, not nil. If you are seeing nil that means the array is probably nil (aka you didnt initialize it).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your array declaration to this and let me know if it works. Hope it helps:

`var studentsArray:Array<StudentData>? = Array<StudentData>()`